# Grid layout for owl carousel

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

Im using ngx-owl-carousel to show some data in my Angular project. The problem is that i want to use Grid Layout but i cannot get it to work

When i try to implement grid, the carousel tells me that there is no data to render, and nothing shows up. What you see in my code now is a solution without grid on my mat tables.

What i need help with is to figure out where to put my divs, so that i can move around my mat-tables. No matter where i put my divs, the carousel stops working.

Thanks.

```
<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div *ngFor="let data of dataSources">
      <ng-container>
          <ng-template carouselSlide [id]="data.id">
    <mat-toolbar>
        <span class="title-center">{{data[0].serviceName}}</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <img class="png-icon" src="../../assets/images/jenkin.png">
     <!-- Change the image dynamically on servicetype-->
    <mat-table [dataSource]=data>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="jobnumber">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Job Number</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.jobNumber}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.serviceName}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.timestamp | date}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="buildtime">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Buildtime</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.duration | date: 'mm:ss'}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="result">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Result</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><mat-basic-chip [ngClass]="element.result === 'ABORTED' || element.result === 'FAILURE' ? 'red' : 'green'"><p>{{element.result}}</p></mat-basic-chip></mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="jenkinsColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: jenkinsColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
</owl-carousel-o>
```

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto, 1fr));
    grid-row-gap: 25px;
    grid-column-gap: 25px;
}

.mat-cell {
    color: white;
}

.mat-header-cell{
    color: white;
}

.mat-header-text {
  color: white;
}

.png-icon {
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  margin-left: 175px;
  margin-top: 230px;

}
.mat-chip{
    background-color: #00ff00;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.warning-mat-chip {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.pending-mat-chip{
    background-color: #ffff00;
}

mat-toolbar {
  background: transparent;
}
.title-center {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 560px;

}

mat-table {
    background: #425F6D;
    margin-left: 160px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 20px; 
}

.red {
  border: 2px solid #8B0000;
  background: #c40000;
}

.green {
  border: 2px solid #006400;
  background: #03bf00;
}

mat-basic-chip {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `ngx-owl-carousel-o` incorrectly.

You can only put the markup for the slides into `<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">...</owl-carousel-o>`. You can do that in this way:

```html
<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
  <ng-template carouselSlide>My slide markup 1</ng-template>  
  <ng-template carouselSlide>My slide markup 2</ng-template>  
  <ng-template carouselSlide>My slide markup 3</ng-template>  
</owl-carousel-o>
```

or in this shorter and enhanced way:

```html
<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of slidesStore">
      <ng-template carouselSlide [id]="slide.id">
        <div class="slide-content-wrapper">slide.content</div>
      </ng-template>
   </ng-container>
</owl-carousel-o>
```

Pay attention to `<ng-template carouselSlide>`. `carouselSlide` is sturtural directive which takes its content and adds later into needed place of the carousel.

You have to keep the hierarchy:

```html
 <owl-carousel-o>
  <ng-template carouselSlide>
    ...
```

or

```html
<owl-carousel-o>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of slidesStore">
    <ng-template carouselSlide [id]="slide.id">
    ...
```

and avoid HTML tags wrapping `<ng-template carouselSlide>`.

I don't know your intention of using the `ngx-owl-carousel-o`, but looking at the css of your example it seems you're trying to arrange 6 slides

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto, 1fr));
    grid-row-gap: 25px;
    grid-column-gap: 25px;
}
```

However, it seems you're making the mistake here. You doubled the rule `grid-template-columns` and the second rule could work incorrectly. `auto` should be changed to any physical value (e.g., px).

To define the number of slides use the option `items`.